# Vue Update Hook Not Firing Every Time

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The updated() hook within my Vue Instance is not firing every time that I trigger a keyboard event (via $forceUpdate() after Vuex is updated).  Is there any way to ensure that the hook gets fired every time?  The process are triggered through keyboard events, but if I type 3 or 4 keys quickly, the updated() hook only gets fired twice!

```
....
methods: {
  keyDown() {
    this.$store.dispatch('updateVuexState', payload)
    this.$forceUpdate() // UPDATES STATE TO THE VIEW //

    // ... SHOULD THEN TRIGGER UPDATED HOOK EVERY TIME IDEALLY, BUT DOESN'T ?? //
    // BASED ON THE TIME SPAN, SOMETIMES HOOK IS SKIPPED ONCE OR TWICE BASED ON //
    // KEYBOARD INPUT SPEED //
  }
},
....
updated() {
  console.log('updated...') // FIRED ONLY WITH A LONGER TIME SPAN //
},
....
```

Comment: [Vue updates *asynchrononously*](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue).

Comment: I see, but not only asynchronously, but queued also.  That poses a problem for me though.  It suggests using nextTick, but I don't see how that's very helpful.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to use $forceUpdate() then if that only really means force update queue, right?

Comment: Yes, I expect $forceUpdate does not trigger an immediate update, rather it only queues an update.

Comment: @Bert ok, thanks, that's pretty disappointing though.

Answer (score 0):

Just use v-model, or without v-model, use `oninput` event instead of `onkeydown` event. And your application will work without forced updates.

Comment: I could use oninput, but I am not directly editing anything.  I am preventing the event and manipulating state manually so I need access to the various keys that the keydown event provides that oninput doesn't.  I can try v-model and see if that helps, but I am manipulating the text content of a contenteditable, so I'm not sure how well that will go.

Comment: I see, so then neither one of those are a possibility then.